# VB Collection cannot be indexed because it has no default property? How to iterate a collection?

Tags: visual-studio, vba, vb6, visual-studio-2005

```
    Dim RS2 As iHistorian_SDK.TagRecordset    
    '...
    For intI = 1 To RS2.Item.Count
        '....
        HistEngHigh = RS2.Item(intI).HiEngineeringUnits
```

Now this gives the error Interface 'VBA.Collection' cannot be indexed because it has no default property. Now it used to work when I ran the code in VBA 6.5 via iFIX but now that I have made a standalone project in Visual Studio 2005 it gives me this error.

So what do I do? What is a default properly and why does it not have one/need one?

Comment: What line are you getting the error on the last one.  If you look at the object definition do you see an item property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I fixed it by iterating it using a for each loop, didn't know I could use it with a custom collection

```
    For Each Item In RS2.Item
        WriteLogFile(Item.Description)
        ...
```